# How to make a field NOT NULL in a multi-tenant database

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

This is a muti-tenant app. All records have a client id to separate client data. Customers can insert their own data in this table and set their own field nullable or not null. Therefore, setting the whole field not null will not work. I need to set a field null for a specific client id.

I am currently querying the database to check if the value is null. On INSERT I check if the inserting value is null if so I throw an error. I would like the database to do all these checks. is this possible in a multi tenant database like this?

Also, I need suggestions for SQL Server, oracle and postgresql. Thanks

Comment: If the users are using a function to write to the DB can you simply write sub function to check if the data entered `IS NULL`

Comment: What do you need code for three different databases?

Comment: @GordonLinoff We have some customers with SQL Server and some with Oracle. I needed postgresql just in case we get a customer with postgresql. We only support these 3 databases.

Comment: This seems to be closely related to one of your recent questions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836035/how-to-set-a-unique-constraint-in-a-multi-tenant-database. You might be able to use a similar approach for both problems.

Comment: SQL tables don't have fields; they have columns. Columns are shared among tenants in a multi-tenant database. So the notion that clients can "set their own [columns] nullable or not" clearly doesn't make sense in terms of columns. CHECK() constraints operate row-wise, but won't easily scale. A uniform interface layer of stored procedures can implement arbitrary logic, but you'll have to maintain three different implementations. How did you decide to use shared tables ("shared everything") rather than one database per tenant or one schema per tenant?

Answer (score 0):

With Postgresql at least you could do this with [table inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-inherit.html).

You could define an inherited table for this specific client which included the required constraint.

Consider the following example:

```
psql=> CREATE TABLE a(client INT NOT NULL, id SERIAL, foo TEXT);
CREATE TABLE

psql=> CREATE TABLE b(foo TEXT NOT NULL, CHECK (CLIENT=1) ) INHERITS (a);
NOTICE:  moving and merging column "foo" with inherited definition
DETAIL:  User-specified column moved to the position of the inherited column.
CREATE TABLE

psql=> INSERT INTO b(client,foo) VALUES (1,'a');
INSERT 0 1

psql=> INSERT INTO b(client,foo) VALUES (1,NULL);
ERROR:  null value in column "foo" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 2, null).
```

The table 'b' in this case inherits from 'a' but has a different definition for column 'foo' including a not-null constraint. Also note that I have used a check constraint to ensure that only records for client 1 can go into this table.

For this to work, either your application would have to be updated to insert client records into the correct table, or you would need to write a trigger that does that automatically. Examples of how to do that are given in the manual section on [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-partitioning.html).

Your application can still make queries against the parent table ('a' from my example) and get the records for all clients, including any in child tables.

Comment: Are you saying he should create a descendant table for every tenant ? if there are too many variety of the configurations, I think this solution won't work.

Comment: @FLICKER of course it would depend on how many clients there are and how many need different column constraints, but you can certainly have hundreds of child tables. I have such a system and it performs well.

Answer (score -1):

You won't be able to do this with a column constraint. Think you're going to have to [write a trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger).