# How to alter the inserted table in a trigger dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to dynamically alter the inserted table in a trigger. I need create a NOT NULL constraint dynamically. I query a Fields table to retrieve NOT NULL fields. Then I create an ALTER DDL query based on the NOT NULL fields. When I execute the ALTER statement it gives me this error.

> Cannot find the object "inserted" because it does not exist or you do
>   not have permissions

Here is the code I am working with:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_INSERT_UPDATE_Data1] 
ON [dbo].[Data1]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
as

DECLARE @ObjectId INT
DECLARE @AlterQueryStr NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT TOP 1 @ObjectId = object_id FROM inserted

SELECT FieldNumber 
INTO #NotNullFieldNumbers
FROM dbo.Fields 
WHERE ObjectId = @ObjectId AND NotNull = 1

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #NotNullFieldNumbers)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AlterTableTemp NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT  @AlterTableTemp = STUFF(( SELECT ';' + 'ALTER TABLE inserted ALTER COLUMN Field' + cast([FieldNumber] as VARCHAR(100)) + ' VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL'
                FROM #NotNullFieldNumbers
              FOR
                XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, '')

    EXEC sp_executesql @AlterTableTemp

END
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to alter the inserted table?  think of it like a special table variable that sql maintains which hold the new values that were inserted or updated into the table.  Altering it wouldn't change the DML operation and changing the data in that table wouldn't change the table the DML operation was on.  Also if it is NULL setting it to NOT NULL would just throw an error if it where allowed.  Seems like the real question is I need to do X (e.g. make sure that a value inserted is not null?).....

Comment: That sounds like a horribly bad idea to alter your database schema **on the fly** inside a trigger....... you need to rethink your approach, this is not a good way to deal with these requirements!

Comment: This is indeed a **horrible** idea. What is the _actual_ problem you are trying to solve with that? Why do you need to dynamically change the NOT NULL attribute of a table? Plus: the `inserted` "table" (variable) only exists for the runtime of the trigger. So there is no point in modifying that.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 @ObjectId = object_id FROM inserted` Hm.. so your trigger work only with 1 `ObjectID`, and if there are 10 rows inserted with 10 different `ObjectID`s?

Comment: Is this is related to your recent questions about a multi-tenant schema where customers can define their own nullability and uniqueness attributes for columns in a table?

Comment: @gofr1 its always going to have the same ObjectId in all records

Comment: @EdHarper yes this is related.

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside the question of why you want to do this, dynamically manipulating the DDL of `inserted` won't work because the `inserted` and `deleted` tables are only accessible within the code of trigger. Dynamic SQL runs in its own execution context (not the context from which it was called), and so you get a `object not found` error.

**Edit:**

Assuming this question relates to your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836035/how-to-set-a-unique-constraint-in-a-multi-tenant-database) [recent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40856650/how-to-make-a-field-not-null-in-a-multi-tenant-database) questions on similar topics, here's one way of approaching this problem using a trigger on a `Data1` table with three `Field...` columns (but this example is extensible to work on more columns).

The trigger works by `PIVOT`ing the `Fields` table into one column per `ObjectId`, then joining this to the `inserted` table and comparing the value of the inserted `Field`*n* with the relevant `Fields.NotNull` value. The code converts `NotNull` values into strings to make it easier to understand, but you could equally use `bit` values.

The code will support `INSERT` or `UPDATE` of more than one value of `ObjectId` in the same batch.

```
--create schema
CREATE TABLE fields (ObjectId int , FieldNumber int ,  NotNull bit)

INSERT fields (ObjectId, FieldNumber, NotNull)
VALUES
(100,1,1),(100,2,1),(100,3,0),
(200,1,1),(200,2,1),(200,3,1)

CREATE TABLE Data1 (ObjectId int , Field1 int ,Field2 int ,Field3 int)

GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_INSERT_UPDATE_Data1] 
ON [dbo].[Data1]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    inserted AS i
            JOIN    (   SELECT ObjectId, Field1,Field2,Field3
                        FROM (
                                SELECT  ObjectId, CONCAT('Field',FieldNumber) AS colName, 
                                        CASE WHEN NotNull = 1 THEN 'NOT NULL' ELSE 'NULL' END AS NotNull
                                FROM fields
                             ) AS s  
                        PIVOT  
                        (  
                        MAX(NotNull)  
                        FOR colName IN (Field1,Field2,Field3)  
                        ) AS p
                    ) AS f
            ON      f.ObjectId = i.ObjectId
            WHERE   (f.Field1 = 'NOT NULL' AND i.Field1 IS NULL)
            OR      (f.Field2 = 'NOT NULL' AND i.Field2 IS NULL)
            OR      (f.Field3 = 'NOT NULL' AND i.Field3 IS NULL)
        )
    THROW 50001, 'Cannot insert NULL into a field marked NOT NULL',1
GO

--Tests

--1 insert good data
INSERT Data1 (ObjectId, Field1,Field2,Field3)
VALUES (100,1,2,3)

--2 NULL blocked for ObjectId 100, Field1 NULL
INSERT Data1 (ObjectId, Field1,Field2,Field3)
VALUES (100,NULL,2,3)

--3 NULL blocked for ObjectId 100, Field2 NULL
INSERT Data1 (ObjectId, Field1,Field2,Field3)
VALUES (100,1,NULL,3)

--4 insert good data (Field3 NULL permitted)
INSERT Data1 (ObjectId, Field1,Field2,Field3)
VALUES (100,1,2,NULL)

--4 multiple ObjectIds supported - NULL blocked for all ObjectId 200 fields
INSERT Data1 (ObjectId, Field1,Field2,Field3)
VALUES  (100,1,2,3),
        (200,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```